# Regex for if a character exists after the last instance of a character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to put together a regex that will indicate whether a character exists after the last instance of a character in a string. For example, the regex would return a match if a period '.' appeared after the last instance of a '/'

So far I am able to find the string combination for the final part of the string after the / using:

```
   [^\/]+$
```

But I am not sure how to only return a match if a period '.' is included in that final string portion. I greatly appreciate any help.

I realize it would be possible to do this by splitting the string, but I was hoping a pure regex way existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/[^\/.]*\.[^\/]*$/       // The whole match is the required result
/.*\/([^\/.]*\.[^\/]*)$/ // and extract Group 1 contents
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/FbKkc8/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/FbKkc8/2/).

The second one is more efficient in practice, as the part after last `/` is usually closer to the end of a longer string, and the match is usually obtained faster.

*Details*

- `[^\/.]*` - zero or more chars other than `.` and `/`
- `\.` - a dot
- `[^\/]*` - zero or more chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of string.

JavaScript demo:

```js
const texts = [ 'a/b/c', 'a/b/c.a' ];
texts.forEach( text => {
    console.log( text, '(/[^\/.]*\.[^\/]*$/) =>', (text.match(/[^\/.]*\.[^\/]*$/)?.[0] || "No match") );
    console.log( text, '(/(.*\/([^\/.]*\.[^\/]*)$/) =>', (text.match(/.*\/([^\/.]*\.[^\/]*)$/)?.[1] || "No match") );
  }
)
```